# iOS push notification banner clear action button

Tags: ios, swift, unnotificationserviceextension

i want to do something when user clear notification from home screen is it possible to get trigger when user tap on clear button on push notification banner, i ended up with adding custom button on view but thats not feasible.

[image]

image is attached i want trigger when user tap on this clear action any idea ???

```
{
   “aps” : {
      “category” : “MEETING_INVITATION”
      “alert” : {
         “title” : “Weekly Staff Meeting”
         “body” : “Every Tuesday at 2pm”
      },
   },
   “MEETING_ID” : “123456789”,
   “USER_ID” : “ABCD1234”

}
```

i have done this but its adding button on view like popup

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
       didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
       withCompletionHandler completionHandler: 
         @escaping () -> Void) {

   // Get the meeting ID from the original notification.
   let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
   let meetingID = userInfo["MEETING_ID"] as! String
   let userID = userInfo["USER_ID"] as! String

   // Perform the task associated with the action.
   switch response.actionIdentifier {
   case "ACCEPT_ACTION":
      sharedMeetingManager.acceptMeeting(user: userID, 
                                    meetingID: meetingID)
      break

   case "DECLINE_ACTION":
      sharedMeetingManager.declineMeeting(user: userID, 
                                     meetingID: meetingID)
      break

   // Handle other actions…

   default:
      break
   }

   // Always call the completion handler when done.    
   completionHandler()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unnotificationresponse/1649548-actionidentifier) about `actionIdentifier`:

> This parameter may contain one the identifier of one of your UNNotificationAction objects or it may contain a system-defined identifier. The system defined identifiers are **UNNotificationDefaultActionIdentifier** and **UNNotificationDismissActionIdentifier**, which indicate that the user opened the app or dismissed the notification without any further actions.

So you don’t have to use your own identifiers, use system’s.

Instead of

```
"ACCEPT_ACTION"
```

use

```
UNNotificationDefaultActionIdentifier
```

and instead of

```
"DECLINE_ACTION"
```

use

```
UNNotificationDismissActionIdentifier
```